# C#: how to generate StreamContent for partial bytes

Tags: c#

How to generate `StreamContent` of  a `filestream` say example  from bytes 5 to 10, I would like to exclude the bytes from 0 to 5.

```
string file = @"C:\Files\test.txt";


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            var X = fs.Length;

            //how to read  StreamContent from bytes from 5 to 10

            var Y = new StreamContent(fs);
        }
```

Comment: 5 to 10 what?  Bytes or characters? Your question talks about streams (bytes) but your code uses a reader (characters). The answer will be different for each.

Comment: I would like to read bytes from 5 to 10

Comment: Then why are you using a StreamReader?

Comment: updated my question, Thanks

Comment: Thanks, 1 more question, can we generate StreamContent for partial bytes. var Y = new StreamContent(fs);

Comment: you need to be *very* careful when thinking about text in terms of bytes - in particular: multi-byte encodings and a possible byte-order-mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read the bytes from a `FileStream` using the `MemoryStream` class. I believe this may be a way to read bytes 5 to 10.

```
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
      if (fs.CanSeek) 
      {
          fs.Seek(5, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          fs.CopyTo(ms, 5);

          //byte[] b = ms.ToArray();
          // create a StreamContent object
          var sc = new StreamContent(ms);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the following:

- *"from bytes 5 to 10"* -- You want to read from 5 inclusive to 10 exclusive, zero-based.  That is, you want to read 5 bytes starting at the *sixth* byte in the file (the byte with index 5, if the first byte in the file has index 0).
- *"exclude the bytes from 0 to 5"* -- Same deal here.  I'm assuming 0 inclusive to 5 exclusive, zero-based.

To visualize what I believe you are asking:

```
Bytes:    #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
Indices:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
You want to read these:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the stream is seekable (as file streams are), seek to position 5 and then read 5 bytes:

```
fs.Position = 5;

var buffer = new byte[5];
var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 5);

if (bytesRead == 5) {
    // Success, process the buffer
} else {
    // Partial read or end-of-file.
}
```

If the stream is not seekable (think a network socket or other pipe, for example), you need to consume and discard the bytes you want to skip.  The simplest way to achieve this would be to read 10 bytes and simply ignore the first five.  (If you wanted to skip a few hundred megabytes then we would want an alternative strategy, as it's probably not a great idea to hold a few hundred megabytes of unneeded data in memory.)

```
var buffer = new byte[10];
var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 10);

if (bytesRead == 10) {
    // Success, process the buffer starting at index 5.
} else {
    // Partial read or end-of-file.
}
```

You can use the [`CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx) stream property to determine whether any arbitrary `Stream` object is seekable.

Comment: Thanks, 1 more question, can we generate `StreamContent` for partial bytes. `var Y = new StreamContent(fs);`

Comment: @user584018 I would assume so, just seek the stream before handing it off. The `StreamContent` docs don't indicate that the stream needs to be seekable or even that the length needs to be known. It's worth a try, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line instead. Writes from 5th character.

Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().ToString().Substring(5,5));

Cheers,
Nagaraj

Comment: `ReadToEnd()` is a *terrible* way to read a small chunk from the middle of a file, and `Substring(5,5)` is not necessarily the same as 5 bytes from offset 5, since multi-byte encodings exist and are common

Comment: Apparently the user changed the question while I was responding. His initial question was related to character - then the question was changed. And yes, I agree if the filesize is large and trying to retrieve first few characters then ReadToEnd is not precise way of doing but on the other hand trying last few character, the answer can considered?